# Delete a record from HTML table using mysql and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hey there i am new to PHP and need to delete a record from MYSQL TABLE where my username resides in html table!
my code for fetching mysql table data into html table is:

```
   while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    $count+=1;
                                    echo "<tr>";

                                    echo "<td>";
                                    echo "<p>";
                                        echo $count;
                                        echo "</p>";
                                    echo "</td>";

                                        echo "<td>";
                                        echo "<p>";
                                            echo $data['myusername'];
                                        echo "</p>";
                                        echo "</td>";

                                        echo "<td>";
                                        echo "<p>";
                                            echo $data['logincount'];
                                        echo "</p>";
                                        echo "</td>";

                                        echo "<td>";
                                        echo "<p>";
                                            echo $data['signindate'];
                                        echo "</p>";
                                        echo "</td>";

                                        echo "<td>";
                                        echo "<p>";
                                            echo $data['signupdate'];
                                        echo "</p>";
                                        echo "</td>";

                                        echo "<td>";
                                        echo "<p>";
                                            echo "<a href='deluser.php?id=" . $data['myusername'] . "'>Del</a>"; //here i want to use this link to delete a user

                                        echo "</p>";
                                        echo "</td>";

                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
```

my deluser.php is:

```
<?php
        //$user=$_GET['myusername'];
        $isConnected=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');
        if($isConnected){
            if (isset($_GET["myusername"])) {
            $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE myusername = " . $_GET["myusername"];
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            // Check the result and post confirm message
            if(!$result){
                echo 'error'.mysqli_error($isConnected);
            }
            else{
                echo 'success';
            }

            }
        }

    ?>
```

suppose that the connection have been set and then i want to delete a record using a wildcard i.e myusername='value for html table'!

The problem is that nothing is showing to me nor an error neither success so is it me doing something wrong can somebody please help me!

Comment: `myusername = '" . $_GET["myusername"] . "'"`

Comment: `?myusername=bobby_tables' or '1'='1`

Comment: Never-ever use GET for data alteration. Just guess what happens when a web spider somehow happens to crawl this page...

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

`mysqli_query()` function first argument must be connection link, why you use `$con` variable? Your connection link to database in `$isConnected` variable. Try use this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($isConnected, $query);
```

And if your `myusername` value is string, you need take this value in single quotes:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE myusername = '" . $_GET["myusername"] . "'";
```

For update information in database, you need use `POST` method, `GET` method is good for information required but not for update, it is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set up your query incorrect. Should be:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE myusername = '" . $_GET["myusername"] . "'";
```

Comment: the query is correct the problem is with is_int() methd